# Is it possible to embed a web application (example: ASP.net/node.js MVC program) into a webpage using an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

I am currently using a web application (online store) but I would like to build an extension to this program (data visualization app) that will be very useful for my clients but I want it to be included in the existing application.

My thought is to build the extension application (likely using something like ASP.net, node.js, etc.) and then using an iFrame to embed this new application.

Is this possible to do? And if it is possible, will I lose functionality of the custom extension app by using the iframe? Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does "extension application" mean to you? It is possible to put `<iframe src="yourapplication"></iframe>` anywhere you want. The question is what functionality from the containing web site you need in the iframe. I suggest reading more about iframes and the restrictions put on them. [MDN has good documentation (with links to more topics)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: Thank you! I will read this, it looks very helpful. I will basically need functionality for the application to communicate to a database and display information.